# Export to a text file the summary of a fit function when using the foreach function

Tags: r

I want to export the summary of the fit function at each foreach parallel loop to a text file.

I am using the **foreach function** from the **doParallel package** (**R**).

Until now I am not been able to do it.

I've tried the following code inside the foreach loop, but it also doesn't work on a normal for loop:

```
sink(file=paste("summary_",i,".txt",sep="")) 
summary(fit_model) 
sink(NULL)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing it for sink:

```
for(x in 1:3){
  sinkFile <- paste0("sink_",x,".txt")
  sink(sinkFile)
  print(summary(glm(rep(x,10)~c(1:10))))
  sink()
}
```